# What does Call: do? -- Call: glm(formula = formula, family = binomial(logit), data = data)

Tags: r, statistics, glm, propensity-score-matching, matchit

I am currently working a Propensity Score Analysis based of off
"Propensity score matching with R: conventional methods and new features" by Qin-Yu Zhao1#, Jing-Chao Luo2#, Ying Su2, Yi-Jie Zhang2, Guo-Wei Tu2, Zhe Luo3.
https://atm.amegroups.com/article/view/61857/html

While doing MatchIt with logistic regression I encounter an issue with the provided code.

```
matchit(formula, data, method = "nearest", distance = "logit", 
       distance.op-tions = list(), discard = "none", reestimate = FALSE) 

m.out <- matchit(Smoke~x.Age+x.Gender, 
                        data=data.complete,
                        distance='logit')

m.out$model
call: glm(formula = formula, family = binomial(logit), data = 
            data)
```

Where I just get the error "Error: object 'Call' not found" I cannot find any examples of Call: online and I am not familiar with the syntax of a single ":".

I've tried searching online for similar implementations and have as of yet fallen short. I am not sure what the output of the code would be.

Comment: That looks like output from a previous command (`m.out$model`, probably), rather than code.  If you just run up to and including `m.out$model`, do you see the `call` line printed?

Comment: Hey, you are correct. It is the first line of the output of m.out$model, Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.